# Android SDK Update causing R folder to not generate?

Tags: android, sdk

I grabbed a fresh copy of the eclipse ADT bundle today and now when I make a new app project the R folder fails to generate (As well as anything else in the gen folder. I also am unable to download API level 18 (Android 4.3).

Did anyone else run into this and if so how did you fix it / or is it something in regards to the switch from eclipse to android studio?

Comment: check properties > Android

Comment: Did you check the error logs for problems? Sometimes when there are errors in the project, the files wont get generated. You can try to fix it by doing a "clean project", if that doesnt help, try clean project and restart the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first

**properties > Android**
if any android version is checked
If ok

Then
**properties > Java Build Path**
check for added dependencies have correct path (Most probably not applied in your case)

If every thing is **Ok** then **Resart Eclipse**

#### Reconfigure your SDK path

**Window >> Preferences > Android browse SDK directory**

Comment: Alright I need ti give it some time to re-download the various versions of android I keep on hand. When that is done I will restart and try again with all luck this will be solved then.

Comment: @CodeMonkeyAlx thats not needed only the latest version is enough to run and build all version

Comment: GOT IT! - Had to restart it again!

Answer (score 0):

When I upgraded to Android ADT rev 22 I got to check `Android Private Libraries` in the tab `Order & Export` of the `Java Build Path` configuration screen. But I suppose it only apply if you depend on libraries. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603396/an-error-occured-after-update-the-android-sdk-tool-rev-22-unable-to-resolve-sup) for details.