# NoClassDefFoundError when creating default display image options

Tags: universal-image-loader

I am gettign NoClassDefFoundError exception in MyApplication.onCreate:

```
      DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .cacheInMemory()
        .cacheOnDisc()
        .build();
      ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new            ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
        .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

User jar of version 1.8.
The same problem (with class com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration$Builder) when I do not use DisplayImageOptions

Here is log

```
05-18 12:46:28.217: E/dalvikvm(5481): Could not find class 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration$Builder', referenced from method com.tappedin.TappedinApplication.initImageLoader
05-18 12:46:28.217: W/dalvikvm(5481): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 81 (Lcom/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/ImageLoaderConfiguration$Builder;) in Lcom/tappedin/TappedinApplication;
05-18 12:46:28.217: D/dalvikvm(5481): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
05-18 12:46:28.217: D/dalvikvm(5481): VFY: dead code 0x0002-0014 in Lcom/tappedin/TappedinApplication;.initImageLoader ()V
05-18 12:46:28.217: D/AndroidRuntime(5481): Shutting down VM
05-18 12:46:28.217: W/dalvikvm(5481): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
05-18 12:46:28.257: E/AndroidRuntime(5481): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 12:46:28.257: E/AndroidRuntime(5481): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration$Builder
05-18 12:46:28.257: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at com.tappedin.TappedinApplication.initImageLoader(TappedinApplication.java:20)
05-18 12:46:28.257: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at com.tappedin.TappedinApplication.onCreate(TappedinApplication.java:12)
05-18 12:46:28.257: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:984)
05-18 12:46:28.257: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3921)
05-18 12:46:28.257: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-18 12:46:28.257: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1098)
05-18 12:46:28.257: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-18 12:46:28.257: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
05-18 12:46:28.257: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
05-18 12:46:28.257: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 12:46:28.257: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-18 12:46:28.257: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
05-18 12:46:28.257: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
05-18 12:46:28.257: E/AndroidRuntime(5481):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok. UIL has nothing to do with this problem.
The problem appared when I upgraded ADT to 22 version.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16610384/120574) I found the solution.