# Fatal Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError <init> when calling new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)

Tags: android

Sometimes when I call this method:

```
public static void initImageLoader(Context context) {
    int memoryCacheSize;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
        int memClass = ((ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getMemoryClass();
        memoryCacheSize = (memClass / 8) * 1024 * 1024; // 1/8 of app memory limit 
    } else {
        memoryCacheSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
    }

    // This configuration tuning is custom. You can tune every option, you may tune some of them, 
    // or you can create default configuration by
    //  ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this);
    // method.
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
            .memoryCacheSize(memoryCacheSize).denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator()).tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO).enableLogging() // Not necessary in common
            .build();
    // Initialize ImageLoader with configuration.
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
}
```

I have this Error when calling ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder:

```
Fatal Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
<init>
0   
 TabsActivity.java line 160
com.byhours.byhours.gui.TabsActivity.initImageLoader
1   
TabsActivity.java line 83
com.byhours.byhours.gui.TabsActivity.onCreate
2   
Activity.java line 4470
android.app.Activity.performCreate
3   
Instrumentation.java line 1052
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate
4   
ActivityThread.java line 1931
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
5   
ActivityThread.java line 1992
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
6   
ActivityThread.java line 127
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600
7 ...   
ActivityThread.java line 1158
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
8   
Handler.java line 99
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
9   
Looper.java line 137
android.os.Looper.loop
10  
ActivityThread.java line 4511
android.app.ActivityThread.main
11 ...  
Method.java line
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative
12  
Method.java line 511
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
13  
ZygoteInit.java line 986
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
14  
ZygoteInit.java line 753
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
15  
NativeStart.java line
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: I am not sure but this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622883/noclassdeffounderror-when-creating-default-display-image-options. Have you seen it?

Answer (score 1):

This is my guess only but your logcat it say that you are trying to call a method that not exists:

```
 Fatal Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError <init>0 TabsActivity.java line 160
 com.byhours.byhours.gui.TabsActivity.initImageLoader
```

So in your code maybe is this line:

```
 ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

Also what line of code you have in "TabsActivity.java line 160"?

To debug you app:
Select you project run it with debug mode and place a breakpoint inside this method...

Comment: the code at the line 160 is :  ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)