# Which aSmack jar file (android-14, android-15, …) should be included to support SDK version 14-19?

Tags: android, android-manifest, smack, asmack

I am stuck between two different errors.

1. [Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610296/android-unable-to-instantiate-activity-class-not-found-exception-after-upgra)
2. [unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray)

In order to fix one I go with solution as mentioned in 1 , and it leads to second error , and vice versa .

1st solution instructs to remove private libraries after going into buildpath , other ask to check mark private libraries.

There is no problem with android - manifest , as there is activity Main specified

My app was working fine until I included asmack jar files to learn xmpp messaging . Now its stuck .

- Downloaded asmack jars from :
  http://asmack.freakempire.de/0.8.10/

I had multiple smack jar files imported in the project that was causing such loop of errors . Now I want to know which version asmack should be imported as to support range of sdks as I am not able to import all jars which causes error as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter, you just need to add one aSmack jar.

Comment: thanks , I see you are managing Smack after going through ignite forums , I have a quick question : Can I use Smack instead of aSmack  for Android which one is better and reliable ?

Comment: No, you can't use Smack on Android

Comment: Looking forward to 2014 GSOC , wish you good luck with Smack for Android

Comment: can you refer me to any open source smack implementation , chat application

Comment: @Flow actually it does matter, lots of Asmack jars have bugs ... it happening right now with me that asmack-4 connecting even connecting to server asmack-8 is crashing