# I am getting these errors while running my Android code

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle, google-cloud-firestore

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
>   Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/measurement/zzabn;
>   :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"


    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "quotspot.inext.quotspot"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:0.1.3'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/myapp/R$array;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870265/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-myapp-rarray)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which aSmack jar file (android-14, android-15, …) should be included to support SDK version 14-19?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738372/which-asmack-jar-file-android-14-android-15-should-be-included-to-support)

Answer (score 2):

Firebase was updated yesterday (5/2), causing the various firebase dependencies you are importing to go out of sync.

The solution is to update them to the latest version, which you can find by:

1. Go to [Firebase release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) for the list of latest versions, or
2. open *build.gradle* file in Android Studio and see which Firebase dependencies are highlighted, put cursor above each of them to see the latest version number

Comment: In that case only Google can fix it :(

Answer (score 0):

try adding multiDexEnabled true in

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
          applicationId "quotspot.inext.quotspot"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please change all these lines of code:

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:0.1.3'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

}
```

to

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:0.1.3'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

}
```

For more informations, please see this [link](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) and [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/).