# Unable to instantiate Activity in Android probblem with com.google.android.maps.jar

Tags: android

I am trying to build an Android application which uses Google Maps. The application is immediately crashing. I have removed JAR files from the buildpath, and cleaned my project, but to no avail. Please help.

```
04-20 18:42:14.452: E/AndroidRuntime(20594): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-20 18:42:14.452: E/AndroidRuntime(20594): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.tabsswipe/info.androidhive.tabsswipe.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "info.androidhive.tabsswipe.MainActivity" on path: /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/info.androidhive.tabsswipe-5.apk
    04-20 18:42:14.452: E/AndroidRuntime(20594):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2232)
    04-20 18:42:14.452: E/AndroidRuntime(20594):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
    04-20 18:42:14.452: E/AndroidRuntime(20594):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
    04-20 18:42:14.452: E/AndroidRuntime(20594):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
    04-20 18:42:14.452: E/AndroidRuntime(20594):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    04-20 18:42:14.452: E/AndroidRuntime(20594):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    04-20 18:42:14.452: E/AndroidRuntime(20594):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
    04-20 18:42:14.452: E/AndroidRuntime(20594):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-20 18:42:14.452: E/AndroidRuntime(20594):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    04-20 18:42:14.452: E/AndroidRuntime(20594):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
    04-20 18:42:14.452: E/AndroidRuntime(20594):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
    04-20 18:42:14.452: E/AndroidRuntime(20594):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-20 18:42:14.452: E/AndroidRuntime(20594): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "info.androidhive.tabsswipe.MainActivity" on path: /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/info.androidhive.tabsswipe-5.apk
    04-20 18:42:14.452: E/AndroidRuntime(20594):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
    04-20 18:42:14.452: E/AndroidRuntime(20594):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    04-20 18:42:14.452: E/AndroidRuntime(20594):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    04-20 18:42:14.452: E/AndroidRuntime(20594):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
    04-20 18:42:14.452: E/AndroidRuntime(20594):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2223)
    04-20 18:42:14.452: E/AndroidRuntime(20594):    ... 11 more
```

My AndroidManifest.xml is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.tabsswipe"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity><meta-data android:value="@string/app_id" android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"/>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" 
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
        </activity>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/> 
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCoNGG7fbUlRzMO74WvSlCai4x3LPzmANs"/>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16610384/833786

Answer (score 0):

Goto:

`Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order & Export and check if Android Private Libraries are already checked and any other library you have imported.`

and then

`Clean`

`Build`

`Run`