# package android.support.v4.util does not exist

Tags: android, android-support-library

Since the last update for android support libraries, I am having issues with importing LruCache. Eclipse, and now even android studio, keep saying that package android.support.v4.util does not exist.

I am using actionbarsherlock and it has included android support v4 and shows no errors. My application was working fine before this last SDK update. What has changed? How do I fix this?

Here is the error that shows:

```
java: /Users/amit/App/src/com/app/EMCache.java:5: package android.support.v4.util does not exist
java: /Users/amit/App/src/com/app/EMCache.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class LruCache
location: class com.app.EMCache
java: /Users/amit/App/src/com/app/EMCache.java:20: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class LruCache
location: class com.app.EMCache
```

Comment: This might be related to [ClassNotFoundException after ADT update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610190/classnotfoundexception-after-adt-update/16610247#16610247) or [Eclipse giving error, missing R.java file after recent update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update/16608570#16608570), which were solutions to common problems in the rev. 22 update.

Answer (score 30):

In my case, the solution was eventually found as documented [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html):

- Make sure you have downloaded the **Android Support Library** using the SDK Manager.
- Create a ***libs/*** directory in the root of your application project.
- Copy the JAR file from your Android SDK installation directory (e.g., `<sdk>/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar`) into your application's project **libs/** directory.

Comment: I got here without checking this answer, as evidenced by my ability to upvote it. Hopefully I will  find it more easily next time I get this error, ie when moving IDE's.

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

After trying tweaking build.gradle different ways, ended up with solution found here:
https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/394#issuecomment-508358572

in short - you can solve it with `jetifier`:

`npm install --save-dev jetifier
 npx jetify`

From the package docs:

> If you use React Native modules with native Java code that isn't converted to AndroidX, and your app is AndroidX, you probably need this.

Answer (score 14):

If you're using `Gradle`, I had to also add this line to the dependencies section of my inner `build.gradle`, the file where you specify your `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`:

```
dependencies {
  compile "com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+"
}
```

I believe the `'19'` is supposed to be whatever your `compileSdkVersion`. If I'm wrong, it will tell you what it's supposed to be.

Comment: You will probably have to update the version to the version in your environment.  eg, for me the version was: "com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.+"

Answer (score 12):

For those importing the support libraries using gradle like this:

```
// compat libraries
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0' // v4
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0' // v7
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.2.0' //v13
```

Remember to remove this all*.exclude module: 'support-v4' from configurations

```
configurations {
    //all*.exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

...might have been a dummy mistake from my part though :)

Comment: Thank you.  Updating the gradle file to use the latest support library ( 23.3.0 as of 2016-04-14) has solved my problem. It was using 23.2.1, and had this problem after an SDK update.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I was porting an Android Googlemaps app API1 to API2, and after many hours I realized I was not adding

```
C:\Program Files\..(your_path_)..
  ..\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\extras\android\support\v4
```

to External Libraries..

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

Step-1: Open Project in AndroidStudio3.3 or above, wait until loading of the project completes.

Step-2: Right click 'app' -> Refactor -> Migrate to AnroidX

Step-3: Review the changes in AndroidStudio console below and click 'Do Refactor'

The issue will be fixed.

Comment: I replace 'import androidx.core.util.LruCache;' with 'import android.util.LruCache;', and then no error

Answer (score 2):

craned's answer:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+"
}
```

worked for me. But (in my case at least) the '19' should match the  compileSdkVersion

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Android SDK's directory and:

jar tvf ./extras/android/support/v13/android-support-v13.jar |grep v4.*util

And within this jar file you can see one of the classes (under v4/util) you have used in your applications.

```
     0 Wed Mar 26 20:29:48 SGT 2014 android/support/v4/util/
  3373 Wed Mar 26 20:29:48 SGT 2014 android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap.class
  5329 Wed Mar 26 20:29:46 SGT 2014 android/support/v4/util/MapCollections.class
  1625 Wed Mar 26 20:29:46 SGT 2014 android/support/v4/util/ContainerHelpers.class
  3677 Wed Mar 26 20:29:46 SGT 2014 android/support/v4/util/MapCollections$KeySet.class
  1220 Wed Mar 26 20:29:46 SGT 2014 android/support/v4/util/DebugUtils.class
  3435 Wed Mar 26 20:29:46 SGT 2014 android/support/v4/util/AtomicFile.class
  1287 Wed Mar 26 20:29:46 SGT 2014 android/support/v4/util/LogWriter.class
  3701 Wed Mar 26 20:29:46 SGT 2014 android/support/v4/util/MapCollections$ValuesCollection.class
  4446 Wed Mar 26 20:29:46 SGT 2014 android/support/v4/util/MapCollections$EntrySet.class
  5910 Wed Mar 26 20:29:46 SGT 2014 android/support/v4/util/SparseArrayCompat.class
  3273 Wed Mar 26 20:29:46 SGT 2014 android/support/v4/util/TimeUtils.class
  5776 Wed Mar 26 20:29:46 SGT 2014 android/support/v4/util/LongSparseArray.class
  5680 Wed Mar 26 20:29:46 SGT 2014 android/support/v4/util/LruCache.class
  3341 Wed Mar 26 20:29:46 SGT 2014 android/support/v4/util/MapCollections$MapIterator.class
  1575 Wed Mar 26 20:29:46 SGT 2014 android/support/v4/util/MapCollections$ArrayIterator.class
  2439 Wed Mar 26 20:29:48 SGT 2014 android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap$1.class
  8611 Wed Mar 26 20:29:46 SGT 2014 android/support/v4/util/SimpleArrayMap.class
```

So the error "package android.support.v4.util does not exist" simply means you have to copy the above jar file to your libs subdirectory and recompile.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was referencing the jar from sdk installation folder, copying the jar to project's libs folder adding to build path actually resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case with Android Studio, this error appeared in the middle of a working project and refused to disappear despite much fooling around. I finally forced a Gradle Sync operation by adding a single space character to a Gradle file. The Gradle Sync fixed it instantly.

Answer (score 1):

> add dependency

```
dependencies { compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'}
```

> Change Build Tool

```
 dependencies {  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'}
```

Worked for me.