# Android support v4

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I have problem in my project. When I'm trying to build my project this error apears in logs:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
  /Users/pawelkoperdowski/Documents/Android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /Users/pawelkoperdowski/Documents/Android/Superplanner/superplanner-android/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/Users/pawelkoperdowski/Documents/Android/Superplanner/superplanner-android/app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
  Error Code:
  2
  Output:
  UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
  com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Ljavax/inject/Provider;
  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
  at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
  at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

So I've read in one of questions here that I should add this to my gradle file:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

But now in classes which use suport I have this errors like this:

```
Error:(21, 33) error: package android.support.v4.widget does not exist
```

My gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'pl.essentialapps.superplanner'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/2'] } }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/"
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile files('libs/guava-18.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.+'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
    compile 'com.splunk.mint:mint:4.0.5'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.6'
    compile 'com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.+'
    provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0'
}
```

I will be very thankfull for any help :)

Comment: i see you have appcompat v7:22.0.0 and support v4:22.1.0. Could you try putting them on the same version?

Comment: remove `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0'` because the support library is also in `appcompat-v7`

Comment: update: you would have to remove the 'configurations' block, too.

Comment: @ChrisK.: I've set both to 22.0.0 and removed configurations block but still same error

Comment: @EpicPandaForce after your solution I have again error "Error:(5, 30) error: package android.support.v4.app does not exist", after that I've removed configurations block, and then it showed "UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:" :/

Comment: try with `minify false`

Comment: Have you read this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621476/package-android-support-v4-util-does-not-exist .

Comment: @EpicPandaForce still "UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:

Comment: @ChrisK. Yes, I've tried to add jar with support but this is also not working :/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to update the `build.gradle`:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

All fields containing `'com.android.support'` should end in `27.1.1`(replace `22.0.0` or `22.1.0` as i see in your program.

Comment: Also remove those lines
        configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        }