# Android R.java doesn't generate

Tags: android, adt, r.java-file

I've just updated the Android SDK to version 22.0 (well, more like a fresh install) and started a new project in Eclipse. I went through the project wizard and everything went fine but then I realised that it didn't generate the build files (neither BuildConfig.java nor R.java).

I searched a bit and found others with similar problems and someone pointed out that after updating a new package should be available called Android Build Tools.
I had installed them as well and BuildConfig.java generated afterwards but I still don't have the R.java.

Some suggested cleaning up the project, editing manifest files and manually adding an R.java file so it would revert back to a generated one but none of these worked, though it showed a warning message in the IDE console when I edited the file but it didn't actually do anything

Comment: Do you have dependencies to other JAR files in your project? if so, go to project references and put a "V" near them. that helped me. tell me if it worked.

Comment: It's one of the most common problems in ADT 22. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update/16608570#16608570) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610190/classnotfoundexception-after-adt-update/16610247#16610247). Edit: added the other solution.

Comment: @Krauxe appreciate you have added this as a comment and not as an answer

Comment: @user2398672 if the answer in the link provided by Krauxe helps go to the link and upvote the same once you gain enough reputation

Comment: @Raghunandan I'm a bit new to answering here and I've learned, thanks to you. :)

Comment: @Krauxe Thanks the second one did the trick :)

Comment: user2398672 give credit to Krauxe. He posted the comment first.

Comment: I was editing just as you replied. Hope it's the right way to do it, if not pardon my incompetence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Go to `Windows->Android SDK Manager`
- Download or update `Android SDK Build-tools`
- Open your project's properties
- In the right panel, choose `Java Build Path`
- In the left panel make sure that `Android Private Libraries` and `Android Dependencies` are checked.
- Clean and rebuild your project

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart the your IDE and create a new project