# R.java cannot be generated although after creating a new Android project

Tags: android, r.java-file

I am not a newbie of using eclipse, I have a serious error after creating a new android project, i noticed that the R.java and the BuildConf.java are not generated.

I have read all posts here about this problem and try all solutions, but nothing helps.
I think that the problem is related to permissions, just thought but still not solve it.

Any idea ??

Comment: If you've recently updated, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update/16608570#16608570) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610190/classnotfoundexception-after-adt-update/16610247#16610247). It's one of the most common problems in the latest SDK.

Comment: Many thanks, the Android SDK Build Tools were not installed, i was trying to install it, but it gives an error, but now I logged as root, then install Build Tools and everything goes well...Many thanks again

Comment: You're welcome! It would be nice if you could upvote my answer which I linked, in case you haven't done so yet. :)

Comment: I already did for both links, thanks again :D

Answer (score 2):

If you have any errors in any of your resources then Android will not re-generate R.java. Fix any errors, and perhaps try to clean your project after that.

Comment: There are no errors n my resources, i just created a new android project without any modifications, also tried cleaning my project, also restarting my eclipse and still have the problem not solved.

Comment: Please update your question with the following details, the Android build version you are using, are you doing _anything_ after you've created the project(imports, creating layouts etc.), what Java version are you using and look at the the Project -> "Build Automatically" option in Eclipse, is it checked?