# Google Ads (Ad View) Error in android application

Tags: android, admob

May be this question is duplicate but its quit strange...

I am working on one application, 
In which i am using an AdView. 
Code was in working condition prior to updation.
Currently i have updated my `sdk to rev 22.0.0`  and eclipse also (i think it is giving me error).

I am working on version 2.2
Using `GoogleAds.jar` (added in libs folder and also in built path).

Also added in Manifest file.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

[this is my add View layout](http://pastie.org/7934472)

the folder in which i have added jars is `libs`.
it is giving me error

```
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abcd/com.abcd.activities.ScheduleActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:684)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:216)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1660)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at com.abcd.activities.ScheduleActivity.onCreate(ScheduleActivity.java:77)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    ... 11 more
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.ads.AdView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.abcd-2.apk]
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
05-20 19:04:23.476: E/AndroidRuntime(29249):    ... 22 more
```

i am not getting what i am missing or where i am doing wrong. Please help me for solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I see you are getting a `ClassNotFoundException`, which might be caused by the recent update to ADT 22. Try *[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update/16608570#16608570)* or *[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610190/classnotfoundexception-after-adt-update/16610247#16610247)* then.

Comment: @Krauxe: any solution over it?

Comment: I linked two solutions on my comment above. Try them.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old, unsupported, version of the AdMob SDK. You'll want to grab the latest version [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download). Note that with this version your activity will need to have the following config changes:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

and have `target=android-13` or higher in your project.properties.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is generated due to unsupported AdMob sdk version or inappropriate use of Admob sdk.

Following are the steps to resolve this problem.

1. Download [admobsdk](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download#downloadandroid) latest version of Admob sdk.
2. Add .jar file of admob sdk in Buildpath of your project (*right click on your project=>Build path=>configure build path=>libraries=>add external jars*)
3. Now your problem will resolve certainly.