# Android Eclipse compilator bug? java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient

Tags: android, ftp

After formatting the computer, eclipse does not want to run the application properly on my android device. Eclipse says there are missing classes. But It's wrong, beaucose the JAR file is imported. Check this screens below:

http://myextreme.pl/img/eclipse/

It crashes on this line:

`Ftp ftp = new Ftp();`

Comment: You might want to try [**this solution**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610190/classnotfoundexception-after-adt-update/16610247#16610247). It's a common issue in the latest ADT.

Comment: I want do do that, but I can't (can't see any upvote arrow, or downvote) . Am I low reputation maybe? Tell me how, then I'll give you upvote :). EDIT: Yeah, I need 2 more reputation to do that :(.