# YouTube Player in Android (YouTubeData API v3)

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I am trying to use YouTubeData API in my android app. (My app need to show the youtube vedio in a part of the screen, then below other widgets). I tried to follow the **Google IO 2012**  [training session](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WFsx-u-q3Y&list=PLhBgTdAWkxeDcgr7lljcTt1bKaHY48Toi&index=2) on **New Youtube Android Player Tools** but I failed the following errors occured.

***YouTube.initialize(this, DeveloperKey)***

The 'YouTube" class is not available in my app, I have already added the library 'YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar' to my lib folder. Does the YouTube class is depricted? I searched it in the [google api reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView) but I cant find any trace of it.

My bad luck is when I tried to run the sample program provided by the google **YouTubeAndroidApiDemo** it return Class not found exception !!

here is the logcat
[image]

Do I have any solution? I want to implement youtube in native api, I have already done this using webview and embedded vedio link.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: are you using this code ?https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/            are you register your app like mention here ? https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register                 do this setup in eclipse  ?  https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/setup                  and after all try to run this project ? https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/         I think you missed something in the way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had the same problem and fixed it. Go to **Java Build Path/Order and Export**. Check **Android Private Libraries**. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>. Clean and build the project. This should fix the error.

This issue is related with ADT 22. After its install this error occurred. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610190/classnotfoundexception-after-adt-update).