# My Android Webview App Closes when I tried to put AdMob Ads

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, admob

Hi My app is forcefully closing and I dont know what is the problem in my code. can any one help..

When I run the apk file it says unfortunately app has been stopped

PACKAGE CODE

```
    package net.learnscripture.webviewapp;

    import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.ads.AdView;
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ComponentName;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.net.MailTo;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import net.learnscripture.webviewapp.R;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public class Dashboard extends Activity {
        public String BASE_URL = "http://mixss.com/Mobile";
        public String DASHBOARD_URL = BASE_URL + "dashboard/";
        public String CONTACT_URL = BASE_URL + "contact/";

    private JavascriptInterface jsInterface;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
        WebView engine = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);


        // Progress bar.
        // With full screen app, window progress bar (FEATURE_PROGRESS) doesn't seem to show,
        // so we use an explicitly created one.
        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        engine.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
            }
        });

        engine.setWebViewClient(new FixedWebViewClient() {
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
            {
                jsInterface.enablePreferencesMenu  = false;
                jsInterface.modalIsVisible = false;
                jsInterface.urlForSharing = null;
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        engine.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        jsInterface = new JavascriptInterface();
        try {
            ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(this, Dashboard.class);
            PackageInfo pinfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(comp.getPackageName(), 0);
            jsInterface.versionCode = pinfo.versionCode;
        } catch(android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        }

        engine.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "androidlearnscripture");
        engine.loadUrl(BASE_URL);
    }

    private WebView getEngine() {
        return (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        WebView engine = getEngine();
        String url = engine.getUrl(); 
        if (jsInterface.modalIsVisible) {
            engine.loadUrl("javascript: learnscripture.hideModal();");
        } else if (url != null && (
                url.equals(BASE_URL) ||
                url.equals(DASHBOARD_URL) ||
                !engine.canGoBack())) {
            // exit
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            // go back a page, like normal browser
            engine.goBack();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem prefs = menu.findItem(R.id.preferences_menuitem);
        if (prefs != null) {
            prefs.setVisible(jsInterface.enablePreferencesMenu);
        }
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.dashboard_menuitem:
            getEngine().loadUrl(DASHBOARD_URL);
            return true;
        case R.id.refresh_menuitem:
            getEngine().reload();
            return true;
        case R.id.preferences_menuitem:
            getEngine().loadUrl("javascript: learnscripture.showPreferences()");
            return true;
        case R.id.contact_menuitem:
            getEngine().loadUrl(CONTACT_URL);
            return true;
        case R.id.share_url_menuitem:
            final String url = (jsInterface.urlForSharing != null
                                ? jsInterface.urlForSharing
                                : getEngine().getUrl());
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("text/plain");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "LearnScripture URL");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, url);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share URL"));
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private class FixedWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith(BASE_URL) || url.startsWith("javascript:")) {
                // handle by the WebView
                return false;
            } else if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
                MailTo mt = MailTo.parse(url);
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("message/rfc822");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{mt.getTo()});
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mt.getSubject());
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, mt.getCc());
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mt.getBody());
                view.getContext().startActivity(i);
                view.reload();
                return true;
            } else {
                // Use external browser for anything not on this site
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                view.getContext().startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    // The methods of JavascriptInterface are called from javascript.
    // The attributes are accessed from the Dashboard class.
    // This is deliberately a dumb container class to stop possible
    // security issues of javascript controlling Java app.
    final class JavascriptInterface {
        public boolean enablePreferencesMenu = false;
        public boolean modalIsVisible = false;
        public int versionCode = 0;
        public String urlForSharing = null;

        public void setEnablePreferencesMenu() {
            enablePreferencesMenu = true;
        }

        public void setModalIsVisible(boolean visible) {
            modalIsVisible = visible;
        }

        // This is useful for allowing the web site to be able to detect
        // old app versions and prompt the user to upgrade.
        public int getVersionCode() {
            return versionCode;
        }

        public void setUrlForSharing(String url) {
            urlForSharing = url;
        }
    }

}
```

Layout Main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:visibility="gone" />
  <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adUnitId="a151b9a90b51ae7"                          
ads:adSize="BANNER"                         
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_engine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Android Manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    package="net.learnscripture.webviewapp"
    android:versionCode="11"
    android:versionName="1.5" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="6"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<meta-data android:value="true" android:name="ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
        <activity
            android:name="net.learnscripture.webviewapp.Dashboard"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">            
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat

```
    06-14 04:53:17.850: D/AndroidRuntime(1105): Shutting down VM
06-14 04:53:17.850: W/dalvikvm(1105): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3f764f0)
06-14 04:53:17.850: I/Process(1105): Sending signal. PID: 1105 SIG: 9
06-14 04:53:17.850: D/AndroidRuntime(1105): procName from cmdline: net.learnscripture.webviewapp
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :net.learnscripture.webviewapp
06-14 04:53:17.850: D/AndroidRuntime(1105): file written successfully with content: net.learnscripture.webviewapp StringBuffer : ;net.learnscripture.webviewapp
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.learnscripture.webviewapp/net.learnscripture.webviewapp.Dashboard}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:638)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1660)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at net.learnscripture.webviewapp.Dashboard.onCreate(Dashboard.java:39)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     ... 11 more
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.ads.AdView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/net.learnscripture.webviewapp-1.apk]
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105):     ... 20 more
```

Comment: post your logcat/stacktrace..

Comment: LogCat Posted see upabove

Comment: @Tarun what is the problem in my code......

Comment: I guess the admob lib is missing.. Add Admob library in libs folder.. Did you add?

Comment: ADMOB_ALLOW_LOCATION_FOR_ADS meta tag is not supported by Admob anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the logcat its clear that AdView class is not available

```
06-14 04:53:17.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1105): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.ads.AdView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/net.learnscripture.webviewapp-1.apk]
```

[ClassNotFoundException after ADT update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610190/classnotfoundexception-after-adt-update)

Comment: visit the link, they have the solution described. or, you can delete all the libraries in libs directory, and then clean your project. Add the libraries then go to Project Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export there check the libraries you are going to use

Comment: You are welcome.. And, if you problem is resolved then please mark it as an answer.