# Running TriggerIO Android ForgeInspector

Tags: android, eclipse, trigger.io

I'm working on a trigger plugin and can't get the ForgeInspector to run at all. I've downloaded that the ForgeInspector and ForgeModule files from the toolkit, and haven't modified anything other that adding some code to API.java. When I attempt to run ForgeInspector in Eclipse, I get:

```
06-14 15:28:17.413: E/AndroidRuntime(7310): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeApp: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeApp
```

I've tried messing around with the classpath (mostly by adding forgecore.jar from ForgeModule to ForgeInspector's libs folder, and manually adding it in the project's properties), but still get this same error.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by a change introduced by the recent Android SDK / ADT update. See [ClassNotFoundException after ADT update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610190/classnotfoundexception-after-adt-update) for a temporary workaround.

That's not an ideal solution, because the classpath is regenerated with the Inspector project every time you update it... We have a fix going into our next platform version: will be released within a week.

Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: This was fixed in v1.4.49 of the platform.