# After Build there is no $1.class in MapView.java

Tags: android, build, osmdroid

I have the Sources of osmdroid and I want to build osmdroid to a jar File and use it in my Project. After the Build, my Project crashes cause of an "ClassNotFound" exception for the MapView class. Within the osmdroid.jar there are 6 MapView .class Files:

MapView$LayoutParams.class

MapView$MapViewDoubleClickListener.class

MapView$MapViewGestureDetectorListener.class

MapView$MapViewZoomListener.class

MapView$Projection.class

MapView.class

So why the Programm cant find the MapView class ?
I looked into the osmdroid.jar that I've downloaded from the Internet. In that Jar were 7 MapView classes. All 6 from above and 1 more called MapView$1.class 
Could that be the reason for the ClassNotFound exception ?
Why does my compiler not build this class File ?

I tryed building a jar by export and building the Project by maven. In both cases the MapView$1.class wasn't built.

Some Ideas ? As I Remember $1 stands for annonymous Classes or Enums, but the MapView.java does not contain such things?...

Thanks and sorry4bad english

Matthias H.

Comment: Is your JAR file in the libs folder?

Comment: yes and added to build path

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at: [ClassNotFoundException after ADT update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610190/classnotfoundexception-after-adt-update)

You likely need to export Android Private Libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that the Problem was the 1.7 Compiler. With Java 1.6 I didnt get the ClassNotFoundException. But the $1.class is still missing :( Do not know why this is in the osmdroid.jar but not in my own build osmdroid.jar..