# Android Offline MBtiles Working Sample

Tags: android, offline, osmdroid, offline-browsing

I downloaded following source from here:
https://github.com/djcoin/MBTilesDroidSpitterExampleSimple

I am have map.mbtiles in the /sdcard/map.mbtiles

I am getting following error:

```
06-22 23:51:12.252: E/AndroidRuntime(29240): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

06-22 23:51:12.252: E/AndroidRuntime(29240): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.XYTileSource
06-22 23:51:12.252: E/AndroidRuntime(29240):    at org.tilespitter.mapboxtiles.MBTilesOsmdroidExample.<init>(MBTilesOsmdroidExample.java:29)
06-22 23:51:12.252: E/AndroidRuntime(29240):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-22 23:51:12.252: E/AndroidRuntime(29240):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
06-22 23:51:12.252: E/AndroidRuntime(29240):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
06-22 23:51:12.252: E/AndroidRuntime(29240):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1982)
06-22 23:51:12.252: E/AndroidRuntime(29240):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
06-22 23:51:12.252: E/AndroidRuntime(29240):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
06-22 23:51:12.252: E/AndroidRuntime(29240):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
06-22 23:51:12.252: E/AndroidRuntime(29240):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-22 23:51:12.252: E/AndroidRuntime(29240):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-22 23:51:12.252: E/AndroidRuntime(29240):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4808)
06-22 23:51:12.252: E/AndroidRuntime(29240):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 23:51:12.252: E/AndroidRuntime(29240):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-22 23:51:12.252: E/AndroidRuntime(29240):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
06-22 23:51:12.252: E/AndroidRuntime(29240):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
06-22 23:51:12.252: E/AndroidRuntime(29240):    at     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am looking for a working Android MBTiles sample.  I am looking for a working android Offline MBtiles sample.  Where is the org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.XYTileSource class?  Can you provide me with a working OSMDroid offline MBtiles example?  OSMDroid has OSMMapTilePackager, OpenStreetMapViewer, GoogleWrapperSample, and others.  I want a specific samples with Offline MBtiles loaded.

Comment: You likely need to export private libraries. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610190/classnotfoundexception-after-adt-update.