# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo. Didn't find class

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

i am trying to use ActionBarSherlock but i always got an error. I already search around the web, but i cant find a solution for my problem.
Here is the error i got :

> 07-24 09:04:03.049: E/AndroidRuntime(2082): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   07-24 09:04:03.049: E/AndroidRuntime(2082): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.moneynotes.view/com.moneynotes.view.SwipeViewActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.moneynotes.view.SwipeViewActivity" on path: /data/app/com.moneynotes.view-1.apk

I already added the actionbarsherlock as library in android category.
my manifest file is like this :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.moneynotes.view"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="SwipeViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check whether the following post solves the issue:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610190/classnotfoundexception-after-adt-update?lq=1][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610190/classnotfoundexception-after-adt-update?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you selected the 'android depedencies' and 'android private libraries' on the 'java build path' catgeory under 'order and export' tab?
if you haven't, try to select it.

Comment: you are right, i did what you told me and  my problems has gone. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest version of ADT(22)? If so, see this post: [ClassNotFoundException after ADT update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610190/classnotfoundexception-after-adt-update).

Answer (score 0):

`android:name="SwipeViewActivity"` should be `android:name=".SwipeViewActivity"` or `android:name="com.moneynotes.view.SwipeViewActivity`