# Intellij Solution for java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, noclassdeffounderror, android-support-library

I had posted this question earlier but hardly anyone viewed it and I recieved no answers after a long time.

Ive been getting this error everytime I click on a button to start a new Activity:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.util.SparseArrayCompat`

This question has already been [answered for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610190/classnotfoundexception-after-adt-update/16610247#16610247) users but I am using IntelliJ. I got this after trying to implement a few libraries in my Android app. Here is my LogCat:

```
08-03 22:47:58.471: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19876): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.origamilabs.library.views.StaggeredGridView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at com.example.PixelBin.ThePixelBinActivities.Top_Fragment.onCreateView(Top_Fragment.java:37)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:870)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:431)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:139)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:804)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1016)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12725)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12725)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12725)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12725)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1075)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2453)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
        ... 34 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.util.SparseArrayCompat
        at com.origamilabs.library.views.StaggeredGridView.<init>(StaggeredGridView.java:296)
        at com.origamilabs.library.views.StaggeredGridView.<init>(StaggeredGridView.java:304)
        ... 37 more
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of this error for IntelliJ users like myself? From the Eclipse solution it seems like its more of an IDE related issue than a code related issue.

Comment: The stacktrace has classes from `android.support.v4.app`, so there is no problem in building probably. Check that your library contains class `SparseArrayCompat` and check that apk contains this class.

Comment: As it turns out, you were correct! For some odd reason, my android support jar didnt have the SparseArrayCompat class in it yet the library that referenced it did have it in it's android support jar. So I simply replaced the jar I had with the jar from the library and it worked out! Thanks