# Android: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, eclipse, classnotfoundexception

I'm getting the following error and I don't no what to do. I cleared my projects 100 times, removed all JARs from the buildpath, deleted bin and gen.....but nothing worked for me.
Please find below the error code:

```
09-03 19:43:17.326: E/Trace(800): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-03 19:43:17.546: D/AndroidRuntime(800): Shutting down VM
09-03 19:43:17.597: W/dalvikvm(800): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
09-03 19:43:17.629: E/AndroidRuntime(800): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 19:43:17.629: E/AndroidRuntime(800): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firsttravel/com.example.firsttravel.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.firsttravel.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.firsttravel-2.apk
09-03 19:43:17.629: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
09-03 19:43:17.629: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-03 19:43:17.629: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-03 19:43:17.629: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-03 19:43:17.629: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-03 19:43:17.629: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-03 19:43:17.629: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-03 19:43:17.629: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 19:43:17.629: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-03 19:43:17.629: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-03 19:43:17.629: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-03 19:43:17.629: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-03 19:43:17.629: E/AndroidRuntime(800): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.firsttravel.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.firsttravel-2.apk
09-03 19:43:17.629: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
09-03 19:43:17.629: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-03 19:43:17.629: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
09-03 19:43:17.629: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
09-03 19:43:17.629: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
09-03 19:43:17.629: E/AndroidRuntime(800):  ... 11 more
09-03 19:43:54.849: I/Process(800): Sending signal. PID: 800 SIG: 9`
```

Do you guys have any idea what is wrong?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Will you please share your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Did you try cleaning and building your app? The stacktrace is clear: `Didn't find class "com.example.firsttravel.MainActivity"` This means that probably your app manifest file is holding a wrong name for the main class, cleaning and rebuilding would solve this error.

Comment: you have typo mistake in AndroidManifest.xml regarding class name.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16610190/389812