# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class after update library

Tags: android

After I change the Google Play Service Liblibrary my application can't run.
When I start it's appear error like this and I tried to fix by google it but still can't fix.
Anybody can explain me on the log bellow:

```
06-10 20:45:13.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18582): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 20:45:13.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18582): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.kidsgame.kidsmath/com.kidsgame.kidsmath.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.kidsgame.kidsmath.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.kidsgame.kidsmath-2.apk
06-10 20:45:13.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18582):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2171)
06-10 20:45:13.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18582):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
06-10 20:45:13.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18582):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
06-10 20:45:13.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18582):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
06-10 20:45:13.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18582):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-10 20:45:13.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18582):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-10 20:45:13.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18582):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
06-10 20:45:13.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18582):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 20:45:13.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18582):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-10 20:45:13.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18582):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
06-10 20:45:13.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18582):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
06-10 20:45:13.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18582):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 20:45:13.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18582): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.kidsgame.kidsmath.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.kidsgame.kidsmath-2.apk
06-10 20:45:13.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18582):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
06-10 20:45:13.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18582):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-10 20:45:13.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18582):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-10 20:45:13.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18582):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
06-10 20:45:13.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18582):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
06-10 20:45:13.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18582):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order & Export and ensure Android Private Libraries are checked for your project and for all other library projects you are using. Clean all projects afterwards and see what happens. Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610190/classnotfoundexception-after-adt-update).

Comment: I hava tried this way, but couldn't help me. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

At this line:

```
06-10 20:45:13.116: E/AndroidRuntime(18582): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.kidsgame.kidsmath.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.kidsgame.kidsmath-2.apk
```

It looks like you've moved the file location of your mainactivity.java or aren't importing a class you need. Try going to your class file and hitting ctrl+shift+o to import anything you are missing, then clean the project