# Util.getDeviceId cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android

Im trying to utilize the code found at: http://androidstream.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/android-how-to-get-installed-applications-list-from-your-application/

The only problem is, line 5 of the example code apparently can be resolved, even though im importing everything from util. Line 5 is as follows:

```
 String deviceId=Util.getDeviceId(getApplicationContext());
```

Any udeas as to the problem and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610190/classnotfoundexception-after-adt-update/16610247#16610247) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608524/eclipse-giving-error-missing-r-java-file-after-recent-update/16608570#16608570), which were solutions to common problems in the rev. 22 update.\
 UPDATE:

It seem this code is used to get IMEI.

```
   String deviceId=Util.getDeviceId(getApplicationContext());
```

Use it instead:

```
 TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String deviceId = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

I think this problem is this page you refer is not show all code, may be there still remain one class Util:

```
public static class Util {
        public static String getDeviceId(Context context) {
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            return telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        }
    }
```

Then it explain why they use : Util.getDeviceId(getApplicationContext()) normally. Just copy this code to your class InstalledAppData. The compiler will clean.

Comment: Updating now, will check back when its revisions are updated.

Hopefully it fixes it!