# Google Maps V2 / Google Play Services NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, google-play-services

I had my maps v2 and the play services all set up, everything worked. After the ADT update to v22, Eclipse started freaking out, giving all sorts of errors on jar mismatches and what not, so I fiddled around a bit.

Now I get the following error when starting my app:

```
05-17 14:58:38.780: E/AndroidRuntime(19908): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
05-17 14:58:38.780: E/AndroidRuntime(19908):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-17 14:58:38.780: E/AndroidRuntime(19908):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
05-17 14:58:38.780: E/AndroidRuntime(19908):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:983)
05-17 14:58:38.780: E/AndroidRuntime(19908):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:968)
05-17 14:58:38.780: E/AndroidRuntime(19908):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:499)
05-17 14:58:38.780: E/AndroidRuntime(19908):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4364)
05-17 14:58:38.780: E/AndroidRuntime(19908):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-17 14:58:38.780: E/AndroidRuntime(19908):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1294)
05-17 14:58:38.780: E/AndroidRuntime(19908):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-17 14:58:38.780: E/AndroidRuntime(19908):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-17 14:58:38.780: E/AndroidRuntime(19908):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-17 14:58:38.780: E/AndroidRuntime(19908):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-17 14:58:38.780: E/AndroidRuntime(19908):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-17 14:58:38.780: E/AndroidRuntime(19908):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-17 14:58:38.780: E/AndroidRuntime(19908):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-17 14:58:38.780: E/AndroidRuntime(19908):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 14:58:38.780: E/AndroidRuntime(19908): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition$Builder
05-17 14:58:38.780: E/AndroidRuntime(19908):    at com.example.myapp.GlobalApp.<clinit>(GlobalApp.java:113)
```

I have the Google Play Services library imported and referenced just as advised by Google. I tried it with and without the `google-play-services.jar` in the libs folder, no difference. Eclipse does not give compile errors on my project. What could be the reason for this?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [ClassNotFoundException on AndroidAnnotations generated classes since update to ADT 22](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16603002/classnotfoundexception-on-androidannotations-generated-classes-since-update-to-a)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Libraries do not get added to APK anymore after upgrade to ADT 22](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596969/libraries-do-not-get-added-to-apk-anymore-after-upgrade-to-adt-22)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to project properties at java build path and check everything from order and export

Comment: That and adding the playservices.jar to the Java build path solved it. Thank you very much =)