# ClassNotFoundException Android Runtime issue

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, classnotfoundexception

I am getting this error at runtime:

```
/AndroidRuntime(1739): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.newsrss.Feed/com.newsrss.Feed.NewsRssActivity}:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.newsrss.Feed.NewsRssActivity
```

I don't understand why. I've ensured my class is named appropriately and referenced correctly in the `manifest.xml` file:

```
<activity android:name="com.newsrss.Feed.NewsRssActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

This is the `class`

```
package com.newsrss.Feed;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.*;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.BaseSwipeListViewListener;
import com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker;
import com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class NewsRssActivity extends shaerToSocial {
```

`shaerToSocial` extends `SherlockActivitiy` (ABS).

I'd really appreciate any help on the isuue, mant thanks

Comment: Can it be the case that you have a project and Android library it depends on?

Comment: is that on your development device or reports from Google Play ?

Comment: @Boris that is possible. I am not the original developer. I am trying to run the application locally for test purposes. I know for a fact that it uses `Facebook SDK`, `Actionbar Sherlock`, `NineOldAndroids`, `Google Play `Services` and few others.

Comment: @Budius - My Development device at work

Comment: what is your API version on the phone? Is lint declaring any new api issue if you run it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924004/android-classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path

Comment: I'm using emulator at the moment, the version is set to API v 15

Comment: check on the build settings if `ActionBarSherlock` is being included in the project build?